# Creating maps in Groovy with functions

Tags: groovy

I am trying to understand if the following Groovy syntax is correct:

```
String f() { return "Hello"}
String g() { return "World"} 

Map myMap = [
  a : f(),
  b : g(),
]

String x = myMap['a']
String y = myMap['b']

assert x == "Hello"
assert y == "World"
```

The Groovy language reference documentation on maps is not clear in this regard:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_maps

Comment: Why it may be not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct. Your case is covered in the first example in the documentation.

```
def colors = [red: '#FF0000', green: '#00FF00', blue: '#0000FF']
```

Think of the syntax as something like this: `[value: expression]`

The keys `a` and `b` become strings (value) and the methods are called to evaluate the expressions.